# How to make smooth curve from end path using pen tool in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool, corners

I am trying to draw a duck sketch in illustrator,

I opened my file from last night and wanted to continue draw from the the highlighted point.

Its taking it as corner point whereas I am looking for smooth movement for duck neck.

Tried watching few videos about add and remove anchor points but not getting desired result.

Please suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resume drawing from where you left off with the Pen Tool just click over an endpoint and drag to set a smooth point handle.

Very likely this will make an anchor point with only 1 handle rather than the 2 you want for a smooth point.

The Anchor Point Tool can be used to change a corner point to a smooth point- just click and drag with it on the point you want to convert. It can also change a smooth point to a corner point by simply clicking on the point. It can be used anytime while drawing a Path or after the path has already been created.

It can be accessed from the Pen Tool stack on the Toolbar or by holding the Alt/ Option key while using the Pen Tool or by pressing Shift+C from any tool.